# browserless/chrome docker taking too much cpu on certain websites

Tags: docker, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

We are using browserless docker to read content on certain websites. For few websites, the CPU increases proportional to the number of sessions open.

Specifics
docker version `browserless/chrome:1.35-chrome-stable`

Script to reproduce once docker is up and running.

```
#!/bin/bash
HOST='localhost:3000'
curl_new_session() {
   echo $(curl -XPOST http://$HOST/webdriver/session -d ' {"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"chrome","platform":"ANY","chromeOptions":{"binary":"","args":["--window-size=1400,900","--no-sandbox","--headless"]},"goog:chromeOptions":{"args":["--window-size=1400,900","--no-sandbox","--headless"]}}}' | jq '.sessionId') | tr -d '"'
 {"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"chrome","platform":"ANY","chromeOptions":{"binary":"","args":["--window-size=1400,900","--no-sandbox","--headless"]},"goog:chromeOptions":{"args":["--window-size=1400,900","--no-sandbox","--headless"]}}}
}

# we open the session and keep it running 
curl_visit_url() {
  local id=$1
  local url=$2
  echo "http://$HOST/webdriver/session/$id/url"
  echo $(curl http://$HOST/webdriver/session/$id/url -d '{"url":"'$url'"}' |jq '' )
}

for i in {1..5}
do
  id=$(curl_new_session)
  echo $id
  curl_visit_url $id 'http://monday.com' &
  sleep 0.5
  echo '.'
done
```

This specific site(monday.com), uses too much cpu but this can happen with other sites as well.

**Question**
Considering we encounter such websites from time to time. What's the best way to handle them?
We want the sessions to be kept alive and not close after opening them.